# "ploughing the earth of our heart"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I would need a verb (or a phrase) that describes what a plough does to the earth (literally) and can apply to ***the earth of our heart*** in a metaphorical way. This is a positive connotation that may involve pain, but leads to a good result. The context could be something like:

> Hardship and afflictions ***____*** the earth of our heart(, plough it), uproot all the weeds so that we may be delivered of every regret, so that we may be able to look forward.

What word would you suggest after "afflictions"? Whatever the plough does to the earth reveals things that were concealed underneath. This is the meaning the author is trying to convey.

I would be grateful for any suggestion, even if it only partially covers all the connotations that I have given.

Comment: *"Plough it ...  so that it may be free to run forward"*, means that the *earth* will run forward. Is that what you wish to say?.

Comment: I will edit my sentence to make it clearer.

Comment: What about 'cleanse'?

Comment: There are some good metaphors in various translations of [Hosea 10:12](https://biblehub.com/hosea/10-12.htm)

Comment: @roblogic: Amazing link, I had no idea that this metaphor existed in the Bible. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. Off the top of my head, I came up with **plow**. Considering how M-W defines the word, I think it would suit your purpose to a nicety—

> : To turn, break up, or work with a plow

> To  make (something, such as a furrow) with a plow

And here is AHD on another meaning of the word—

> To make or form with driving force: *I plowed my way through the crowd.*

> To progress (through water) : *plow the high seas.*

Thus, the two connotations you are seeking are nicely encapsulated in this word.

Another beautiful and short word that fits the context is **till**, which AHD defines as—

> To prepare (land) for the raising of crops, as by plowing and harrowing; cultivate.

*On a personal note, I like **till** better than **plow** because it seems to convey better the sense of roiling up the earth for something productive.*

Comment: Note that "plow" is American spelling and "plough" is the British spelling.

Comment: @Chasly: Thank you, I am looking for the British spelling.

Comment: @chasly- supports Monica— I have come across this word innumerable times, but had never thought _Plough_ is the British version of _Plow_. But thank you for enlightening me. :)

Comment: They are of course pronounced exactly the same!

Comment: @user405662: This _roiling up_ is interesting... So you can roil up earth?

Comment: @user405662: Oh, wait, I am not looking for something cheesy! Actually, what do you mean by cheesy?

Answer (score 12):

> Hardship and afflictions **till** the earth of our heart(, plough it), uproot all the weeds so that we may be delivered of every regret, so that we may be able to look forward.

**To till** has the advantage of being a little old-fashioned, and this suits religious language.

OED:

> **till** (*v) tr., intr, absolute*
>
> **4.a.** transitive. **To bestow labour and attention, such as ploughing, harrowing, manuring, etc., upon (land) so as to fit it for raising crops; to cultivate.**
>
> 1625   N. Carpenter Geogr. Delineated ii. i. 8   *Every man began..to till & manure the soil.*
>
> **4 b. spec. To plough (land).**
>
> 1863   H. Fawcett Man. Polit. Econ. i. iv. 48   *The same ploughs till the land for many successive crops.*
>
> **6.** *figurative.* **To cultivate (something figured as land or as a crop, e.g. the mind, a ‘field’ of knowledge, a virtue, etc.).**
>
> a1764   R. Lloyd Author's Apol. in Wks. (1774) I. 6   *And tills their minds with proper care.*

Comment: I am frustrated that I cannot accept two answers for the same question...

Answer (score 3):

The word is *Break*.

Clearly the meaning is to *break* the earth of our hearts. It is to break our heart so that from the pain there will be growth. That we may be delivered of every regret, so that we may be able to look forward. The meaning of the action is the explicit, future, good purpose of the result.

Comment: "break" might turn the reader in the wrong direction. To break someone's heart with a good purpose is rather unusual.

Comment: The desirability of a broken heart is an extremely common notion in Judeo-Christian literature, for example [Psalms 51:17.](https://www.bible.com/bible/1/PSA.51.17.KJV)

Answer (score 3):

Ploughs *turn* the earth.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn)

> **turn**: 3 a (1): to dig or plow so as to bring the lower soil to the surface
> *turn the compost weekly*.

Answer (score 2):

The plough *breaks ground*

> New Jersey Ag Agents often field calls like this from beginning farmers with small acreage and urban ag market gardeners who need to perform primary tillage, i.e., **break ground** for the first time. Working with a limited budget, they face the daunting task of opening up an old pasture like our farmer’s, or soils that are compacted and abandoned. ([sustainable-farming.rutgers.edu](https://sustainable-farming.rutgers.edu/farm-calls-tillage-tools-for-breaking-ground/))

Metaphorically, you could say: "Hardship and afflictions **break up** the earth of our hearts..."

Other options are *furrow* and *gouge*, both verbs:

**Furrow**:

> to form or cut a long line or hollow in the surface of something ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/furrow))

**Gouge**:

> to dig or cut into something in a rough or violent way ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gouge))

"Hardship and afflictions *furrow* the earth of our hearts, rooting out weeds of..."

Answer (score 2):

Although you've already accepted an answer, I would suggest ["harrow."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harrow)

Unlike plowing, which does *not* make a field easier to travel, harrowing leaves a smoother finish to the soil. It is often used as a way to remove weeds from a large area.

Further, harrowing is sometimes used in an alternate sense to describe a trial or hardship, which fits your metaphor.

Comment: "Harrowing" has another, very negative connotation.  This does not fit OP's described needs.

Comment: I'm not sure. The negative connotation is one of hardship and affliction. But that's what builds character.

Comment: "Harrowing" is incredibly frightening, as in a Chucky movie.

Comment: @erickson: This sentence is about something negative as you say, "hardship and affliction" that has _**a positive**_ effect. So yes, HotLicks is right. Without looking in the dictionary, for me something "harrowing" is something that transfixes you with fear. So it doesn't go here.

Comment: @fev Farmers don't harrow their fields to get negative results. It's a preparation for planting new seed. "Harrow," with this positive connotation, is sometimes used in religious contexts; I can't tell if your quote is from a religious or spiritual text, but it shares the same tone as a lot of religious commentary. As part of the agriculture metaphor, I personally would interpret it as harrowing the earth. But I guess more people are ignorant about how they are fed than I realized.

Comment: @erickson: I understand your point and you are right. What I did not manage to pass across in my former comment is that "harrowing" with the meaning I gave is much more used than "harrowing the earth", as you can see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=harrowing+the+earth%2C+harrowing+look&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Charrowing%20the%20earth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Charrowing%20look%3B%2Cc0).  One farming question: Is harrowing more superficial? Which reaches deeper in the earth, ploughing or harrowing?

Comment: @fev Yes, that makes sense. I acknowledge that "harrowing" today is much more commonly used in the sense of a "harrowing experience." I just didn't realize that so many had lost touch with its root meaning. Harrowing is more superficial than plowing. It can be done after plowing to smooth a field for broadcast seeding, and regularly for weed control. Like any agricultural practice, done wrong, plowing can be extremely destructive, and that is why we sometimes use "plow" with a negative connotation too: "The van plowed into the helpless crowd."

Comment: There's always "tilling".

Answer (score 1):

> Hardship and afflictions ? the earth of our heart(, plough it) and
> uproot all the weeds, so that we may be free to run forward.

The intention of this is perfectly clear as a metaphor and it is correctly phrased. . However I'm not convinced that the metaphor makes sense. It is a lot easier to run on unploughed land than on ploughed land. This is because the furrows and the loose soil will slow you down and trip you. I know, I have tried!

[image]

---

**Note**

A capital is required after a question mark: Hardship and afflictions? **The** earth of our heart."

Also, in English we do not leave a space between a punctuation mark and the preceding word.  Thus "afflictions?", not "afflictions ?".

Comment: I do apologize about the "running". I did not mean it in that way. I have edited again to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

In view of a comment below, I have changed my answer.

**scour**

> scour - 5. To clear (an area) by freeing of weeds or other vegetation
> https://www.thefreedictionary.com/scour

---

```
**Old answer**
> Hardship and afflictions ... the earth of our heart; uproot all the
> weeds so that we may be delivered of every regret, so that we may be
> able to look forward.

I have modified it a little as follows:

Hardship and afflictions are the earth of our heart. Uproot all the weeds so that we may be delivered of every regret; so that we may be able to look forward.


This makes sense in the form above. It is a convincing metaphor.

**Note**

I used a semicolon to replace a conjunction as follows:

Hardship and afflictions are the earth of our heart. Uproot all the weeds so that we may be delivered of every regret **and** so that we may be able to look forward.

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/semicolon/
```

Comment: I am sorry for my confusing formatting. The  ... were meant to be replaced by the word I am requiring.

Comment: Okay. The first word that comes to mind is "scour".  *"scour - 5. To clear (an area) by freeing of weeds or other vegetation"*  https://www.thefreedictionary.com/scour

Comment: Okay, the first word that comes to mind is "scour". I have edited my answer.

Comment: Most people associate "scouring" with steel wool and kitchen sinks.  It also sounds quite similar to "scourge" (whip brutally), which has highly negative connotations.  All in all, a scoured/scourged heart sounds like it would turn into a mess of scar tissue, not be purified.

Comment: @lambshaanxy  - I agree. However the dictionary definition is spot-on with regard to the meaning. It is not my fault that two similar-sounding words have different meanings. **scour** comes from  Latin excurare "clean off," literally "take good care of," - **scourge** comes from Old French  escorgier meaning "to whip," (From https://www.etymonline.com/) - Perhaps you have a better-sounding solution? I think that the trouble comes from the original metaphor. Cultivating land is a rough old business. Hard work, and you get your hands dirty.

Comment: Submitted an edit to remove unnecessary version history. Remember, anyone who wants to can see the full edit history of an answer, so you don't need to mark edits or maintain previous copies of an answer.